# React Native: Is there a way to make components scrollable/sticky without using ScrollView?

Tags: react-native

New to react native. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Render a page with three components: top panel, middle row, and content box.
2. When the user scrolls down, the top panel is scrolled and disappears, middle row is scrolled but is sticky to the top of the screen, and the content box is scrolled all the way down until the end of the content.

Below code serves my intention. However, when I use this code, I get warnings about nesting virtualized views.

```
return (
    <View style={style.profileContainer}>
        <ScrollView
        stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
        <TopPanel /> // This is a view component and is scrolled up as the user scrolls down.
        <MiddleRow />  // This is a view component that is sticky to the top of the screen
        <BottomArray /> //This is a FlatList
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
)
```

Below code gets rid of the warning but all the scroll/sticky behaviors of the top/middle components disappear. They just remain fixed as the user scrolls down.

```
return (
    <View style={style.profileContainer}>
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <TopPanel /> // This is a view component and is fixed as the user scrolls down.
        <MiddleRow />  // This is a view component and is fixed as the user scrolls down.
        <BottomArray /> //This is a FlatList
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
)
```

Is there a way to make the top panel scrollable and middle row sticky without relying on ScrollView? This is one of the key interfaces of the app and I'd like to keep it alive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put the Middle Row inside a Scroll View, that will help. I am new to react-native, so I am pretty sure this won't help you a lot and I think you would have already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you are looking to achieve, you can wrap the 3 boxes inside a view, have the top and middle inside a view and the content inside a scrollview:

```
<View>
  <View><Text>TOP SECTION</Text></View>
  <View><Text>Sticky section</Text></View>
  <ScrollView><Text>...Content</Text></ScrollView>
</View>
```

then using animate you can animate the size (for the top section) and the position (of the sticky section) based on the scroll position of the content section.

first you define you scrollY as a ref:

```
const scrollY= useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

then you convert the views to Animated and "link" the scrollY ref to the scrolling of the scrollview:

```
<View>
  <Animated.View><Text>TOP SECTION</Text></Animated.View>
  <Animated.View><Text>Sticky section</Text></Animated.View>
  <Animated.ScrollView 
   scrollEventThrottle={16} 
   onScroll={Animated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }], // attach the scroll to scrollY
  { useNativeDriver: true }, 
)}>
   >
    <Text>...Content</Text>
  </Animated.ScrollView>
</View>
```

at this point you can define the function that handle position, size, opacity and so on based on the scrollY position, assuming you know the header height, this function interpolate (map the values)  the scroll position of the scrollview from 0 to the height of the header, giving an innverse output range (from 0 to -header heigth):

```
const headerTranslateY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, HEADER_HEIGHT],
    outputRange: [0, -HEADER_HEIGHT],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
```

this function can be attached to the trasform property of the style of the view that you want to animate:

```
<Animated.View styles={[styles.customstyle, {transform: [{ translateY: headerTranslateY }]}]><Text>TOP SECTION</Text></Animated.View>
```

basically with interpolate you constatly set values of something, based (in this case) of the scrolling offset of your scrollview (you can read more here on interpolation https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#interpolation)